# How to Host Node.js with EJS Templates on CentOS 7 with Reverse Proxy Using Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, centos, ejs, reverse-proxy

I am currently facing an issue with my Node.js application using EJS (Embedded JavaScript templates) on CentOS 7. Whenever I attempt to change the route, I am redirected to the EJS error page. Even if I refresh the page, it continues to redirect me to the error page. I would greatly appreciate your guidance on resolving this matter.

**Additional Information:**

I have attempted to configure the routing in my .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.app$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.app$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.app\:3000\/" [R=301,L]
```

My application is running on example.app, and I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy to redirect requests to my Node.js application running on different port 3000.

Any insights into why the routing is causing redirection to the EJS error page and how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance.